# Missing libraries uFCoder

Tags: c++, linker, rfid

I need to use uFCoder in a project but I got 'undefined reference to' errors. I just have a .h and a .dll and can't find on their website where are the .a or .lib for windows. Is it possible that I only need the .dll and the .h ?

Comment: It's possible. GCC toolchains for Windows can link DLLs directly.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I've search but haven't found how to do it. Should I consider the DLL as a .lib ?

Comment: DLL stands for "Dynamically Linked Library" so it is the library file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GCC, and you have `uFCoder.dll` stashed in `\some\path`,
you can link it with the linkage options `-L/some/path -luFCoder`. This
implies a non-unix-standard way deducing the library name, but GCC supports
it on Windows. Then at runtime, of course, `uFCoder.dll` must exist somewhere
where the OS can find it in accordance with the [Search Path Used by Windows to Locate a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx)

Beware however that if you haven't got a DLL that was built with GCC, it's not going to be binary compatible.

Comment: I tried what you said, it wasn't successful. I guess the DLL wasn't built with gcc. I'll try to contact d-logic directly.